# How can I make a checkbox print one report if checked, another if left unchecked?

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, report

I am using Access to print employee reports and I have built a search form to facilitate this and query these reports. I have detail and summary reports and I want to make it so I only have one button for the open report, preview report, and print report buttons, instead of one set for detail and one set for summary. Here are a couple of pictures to illustrate what I need.

[image]

This is what I have currently.

[image]

And this is what I want.

How can I configure the checkbox to open/preview/print out the detail if unchecked and summary if checked? Also I'd prefer to not use VBA code if possible - as managers who don't know code let alone Access very well will have to use this in the future.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use VBA for this in your OnClick event of the button:

```
Dim ReportName As String

If Me!CheckSummary.Value = True Then
    ReportName = "NameOfNormalReport"
Else
    ReportName = "NameOfSummaryReport"
End If
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt feedback Gustav! I'm testing another aspect of the reports right now but I will check this within the next 15-20 minutes and get back to you. Quick question:  Over here the command is DoCmd.OpenReport. Would I just change this to
DoCmd.PreviewReport and
DoCmd.PrintReport for the print and preview buttons?

Comment: Yes. Missed that, sorry. But you would only have two buttons ... preview and print. What does open do?

Comment: I guess it's not really necessary but for right now I've been opening them so I can play with the preferences and keep on making adjustments to some of the settings (headers, footers, etc).

Comment: For the checkbox code, would I need a checkbox for each button (ie 1 checkbox to have detail preview change into summary preview, and one to change detail print into summary print)? Or would there to be a way to have one checkbox change both buttons?

Comment: One checkbox is enough.